# mongoid search a full string and see if array element is a substring

Tags: ruby, regex, mongodb, mongoid

```
Game.any_in({:array => /#{searchT}/i})
```

the `searchT` is a variable so lets say the array field has a array value

```
["test", "something", "i", "go here"]
```

and the string to search by is `"Hi my name would go here"`

I need to see if the array elements are a substring of the search string in ruby using mongoid.

I was thinking of splitting the string, but I think there might be a easy regex way of doing it.

Comment: So you need to search the `array` field to see if any of the array elements contain any of the words in `searchT`, right?

Comment: If you search for anchored regex and mongodb you'll find the only efficient way to do text searching in MongoDB. If you want more complex stuff (that is supported in production), SolR/ElasticSearch may be a better choice.

Comment: I think I'd go with @WiredPrairie's FTS approach too, if the regex isn't anchored at the beginning then it won't use any indexes and that means that the search will hit every document in the collection (LIKE and regex queries in relational databases suffer the same problems). A proper search system will perform better and offer some other conveniences too.

Comment: I found a elasticsearch hoster, so it does seem it has quite a lot of added benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoid search gem: https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search